# Python - Extracting data from this Html tag using BS4, instead of getting None

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is my code:

```
html = '''
<td class="ClassName class" width="60%">Data I want to extract<span lang=EN- 
UK style="font-size:12pt;font-family:'arial'"></span></td>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('td').string)
```

It returns None. I think it has to do with that span tag which is empty. I think it goes into that span tag, and returns those contents? So I either want to delete that span tag, or stop as soon as it finds the 'Data I want to extract', or tell it to ignore empty tags

If there are no empty tags inside 'td' it actually works.

Is there a way to ignore empty tags in general and go one step back? Instead of ignoring this specific span tag?

Sorry if this is too elementary, but I spent a fair amount of time searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.text` property, not `.string`:

```
html = '''
<td class="ClassName class" width="60%">Data I want to extract<span lang=EN-
UK style="font-size:12pt;font-family:'arial'"></span></td>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('td').text)
```

Output:

> Data I want to extract

Comment: Thanks, it is so simple :$. What is the difference exactly? It seems it makes much more sense to just always use .text?

Comment: @TheProgramMAN123 `.string` is NavigableString: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring. `.text` gets all the text, even from sub-elements, that's probably what you want most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.text`:

```
>>> soup.find('td').text
u'Data I want to extract'
```